# How to combine 2 rows into single row in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a resultset in the below-mentioned form returned by a SQL:

```
ID   Key
1    A 
2    A
3    A
```

Now my requirement is to show the data in the below form:

```
Key ID1 ID2 ID3
A   1   2   3
```

How to build an SQL for this?

Comment: Google pivot teradata.

Comment: Do you know how many columns this will be when writing the query? Is this always three values? If so, you can use PIVOT or conditional aggregation. Usually such display thing is something you would not do in SQL, but in your app or website.

Comment: There is only one column ID which needs to be shown like this.

Comment: @kannanm: Which teradata version are you using?

Comment: I am using 14.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windowed Aggregate based solution with a single STATS-step in Explain:

```
SELECT
   key,
   -- value from 1st row = current row
   ID AS ID1,
   -- value from next row, similar to LEAD(ID, 1) Over (PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY ID)
   Min(ID) 
   Over (PARTITION BY Key 
         ORDER BY ID 
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following) AS ID2 ,
   -- value from 3rd row
   Min(ID)
   Over (PARTITION BY Key
         ORDER BY ID
         ROWS BETWEEN 2 Following AND 2 Following) AS ID3
FROM mytable
QUALIFY -- only return the 1st row
   Row_Number()
   Over (PARTITION BY key
         ORDER BY ID) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As teradata 14.10 doesn't have a `PIVOT` function and assuming that for every unique `key`, there will be no more than 3 `IDs`( as mentioned in comments), you can use `row_number()` and `aggregate` function as below to get your desired result.

```
SELECT
  key1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ID END) AS ID1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN ID END) AS ID2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN ID END) AS ID3
  FROM 
  (SELECT
  t.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY ID) AS rn
  FROM table1 t) t
  GROUP BY key1;
```

**Result:**

```
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
|    key1    | id1 | id2 | id3 |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| A          |   1 |   2 |   3 |
+------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/UDQXF33055)**